# How to logically check the shape of an array in an IF-statement?

Tags: arrays, if-statement, fortran

Is it possible to check if an array is a certain shape using an IF-statement? I have tried the following with no success.

```
program main

   implicit none

 ! Local variables. 

   integer, dimension(3,3) :: a
   integer, dimension(3,3) :: b

  ! Check if a is a 3x3 array.

    if (shape(a) == shape(b)) print *, "Works"

end program main
```

But I get the error:

`Error: IF clause at (1) requires a scalar LOGICAL expression`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(shape(a) == shape(b))` is the logical array `[ T T ]` because it compares the first rank of `a` to the first rank of `b` and so on.

You need a logical scalar: `(all((shape(a) == shape(b)))` ensure that every dimension is the same.